# Scala: map function not returning desired result

Tags: scala, list, foreach

I am coding a scala function that has to return a `List[TaskSchedule]`.

If I do it like this, it returns the desired type:

```
val taskSchedules = orders.flatMap { order => createSchedules(order, order.prod.tasks) }
```

The thing is that I want to run `createSchedules` n times, so I did this:

```
val taskSchedules = orders.map { order => (1 to order.quantity) foreach ( _ => createSchedules(order, order.prod.tasks) )}
```

But this way, taskSchedules are from type `List[Unit]`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are doing `foreach` inside map which returns void(or `Unit`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach returns Unit so you are mapping orders from List[OrderClass] to List[Unit].

I am not 100% sure what your goal is, however, assuming your goal is to have in the end the same type (just create multiple results from each createSchedules and createSchedules returns a list too) then you would want to do:

```
val taskSchedules = orders.flatMap { order => (1 to order.quantity) flatMap ( _ => createSchedules(order, order.prod.tasks) )}
```

Comment: Tell me just one more thing. Is there a way to get the index of the instance so I can send it as a parameter to the createSchedules function?

Comment: What do you mean the index of the instance? If you mean the order instance then you can either use zipwithIndex or simply iterate over orders.indices and get order by orders(i). If you mean the indices for the order quantity, then just name it instead of using _

Comment: @JCosta you need `(1 to order.quantity).map(index => createSchedule(index, ...))`. `_` in the answer is just a placeholder, replace it with any name you want.

Comment: prayagupd's helped me. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

using for comprehensions is an idomatic way to achieve this in Scala.

```
val taskSchedules = for {
  order <- orders 
  _ <- 1 to order.quantity 
} yield  createSchedules(order, order.prod.tasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `.foreach` inside `.map`, the final response is going to be `List[Unit]` because `foreach` is no-return operation. see `List#foreach` for example,

```
  // Overridden with an implementation identical to the inherited one (at this time)
  // solely so it can be finalized and thus inlinable.
  @inline final override def foreach[U](f: A => U) {
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      f(these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
  }
```

So, better use `.map` whenever response matters, not just kind of fire and forget with `foreach`.

Example,

**input**

```
scala> val orders = List(("orderA", 1), ("orderB", 2))
orders: List[(String, Int)] = List((orderA,1), (orderB,2))
```

**function that returns response**

```
scala> def scheduleOrder(order: String) = s"$order will be shipped"
scheduleOrder: (order: String)String
```

**process the input n number of times and store the results**

```
scala> orders.map( order => Range.inclusive(1, order._2).map(counter => scheduleOrder(counter +"-" +order._1))).flatten
res9: List[String] = List(1-orderA will be shipped, 1-orderB will be shipped, 2-orderB will be shipped)
```